# BMI calculation from two columns of a pandas data frame with missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am still at the beginning of my Python career and I am trying to add a column with the BMI in a DataFrame, which is calculated from two other columns. However, this does not work with my code yet and maybe someone can help me! In my data I also have relatively often no information and then I just want "NaN" and I think that's the reason why my code doesn't work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['m', 'w', 'm', 'm'], 
                   'bodyheight': [1.80, 1.70, 1.85, 'NaN'], 
                   'bodyweight': [75, 59, 83, 90]}, 
                  columns=['gender', 'bodyheight', 'bodyweight'])
df.apply(lambda x: (x.bodyweight/(x.bodyheight**2)), axis=1)
```

Comment: You can use `.fillna()` to replace NaN values with a default.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a string `NaN` in there. You could replace that with an actual NaN value; then use vectorized division (also I feel like you forgot to divide the height by 100 to convert centimeters to meters):

```
df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)
df['BMI'] = df['bodyweight'] / df['bodyheight'].div(100).pow(2)
```

Output:

```
  gender  bodyheight  bodyweight        BMI
0      m       180.0          75  23.148148
1      w       170.0          59  20.415225
2      m       185.0          83  24.251278
3      m         NaN          90        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @Lina you're welcome; just realized that you had already divided the heights by 100 (for some reason I thought they hadn't been), so disregard that part; cheers